# Why was I able to default construct an object without a default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Here is a line of a function on the border layer between C and C++. The function gets a bunch of `void*`
and casts them to types they should be. Spot the bug:

```
MDLPeriph periph_dline = *static_cast<MDLPeriph*>(dline_periph);
```

Indeed, periph_dline should have been a reference. What puzzles me is that this code compiles without warnings. Furthermore, `gdb` when inspecting this code, reports an `Internal GDB error.` and crashes.

As far as I understand, the above code default-constructs an MDLPeriph object. Then is uses the new object's copy constructor to assign the value from the right side.

But MDLPeriph has NO default constructor! How was this possible?

Platform and tools:

> Windown 7
>   This build of yagarto use the following versions:
>
> binutils: 2.23.1   gcc:      4.7.2   newlib:   1.20.0   gdb:     7.5.1
>
> (22.12.2012, mifi)   openocd o.7.0

Comment: It's a direct copy construction. No default construction involved. @Andreas No, classes can be without default constructors. A default constructor is implicitly declared only if the class has no user-declared constructor whatsoever.

Comment: @Andreas: No, a class doesn't necessarily have a default constructor. See for example the answers for the question you linked to.

Comment: Oh damn, yes, missed the fact that a default constructor will not be generated when there are **any** other constructors available ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing being default-constructed here.

The pointer cast causes whatever `dline_periph` points to to be interpreted as a `MDLPeriph` object, without creating a new object; that is then used to copy-initialise `periph_dline` using its copy constructor.

Comment: So a new object is still being constructed, but the assignments of it's members are done during construction?

Comment: @Vorac: `periph_dline` is a new object, initialised using its copy-constructor (which, unless it's been defined to do something weird, will copy-initialise each of its members).